# subir mega datos mysql maria db xamp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mariadb

Buen día

tengo una web en xampp y maria db

he programado una función para subir archivos en formato csv y volcarlo a base de datos

pero si son mas de 14mil lineas, sube los campos en blanco, no copia nada y se queda en un loop generando lineas en blanco que superan la cantidad de lineas que contiene el csv

Pero si son menos de 14mil lineas si las copia,

la pregunta es:

1. es cuestión de programación (ver código)
2. o es cuestión de configuración del xampp (que debo configurar)

PD: he aumentado en el config del xampp el max_execution_time=9999, por si acaso excede del tiempo de subir el archivo.

El código insertado para subir el csv es el siguiente:

```
    include ("conexion_bd.php");

        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($file, "r");
            $c = 0;
            while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false)
            {
                $referencia = $filesop[0];
                $descripcion = str_replace('"', ' Pul.',$filesop[4]);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO " . TABLE . " (referencia, descripcion) VALUES ('$referencia','$descripcion'' )");
                $c = $c + 1;
            }
```

Comment: Tenes una comilla simple de más aca: `...,'$descripcion'' )");`. Estas usando mal `str_replace`, debería ser algo como `str_replace('"', '', ' Pul.',$filesop[4]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente el limite de upload exceda cuando subes archivos de ese peso ya que tiene muchas lineas.
Modifica tu archivo php.ini buscando las siguientes variables:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 180
memory_limit = 64M
```

Ahora bien configura estas variables según a lo que necesites. No olvides reiniciar apache luego de guardar las modificaciones que realizaste.